# Php using str_replace for strange template string?

Tags: php, explode, str-replace

Not sure if this is possible, but on my template I have this in the code:

```
Title Here<!--firstTitle-->
```

I am wondering if there is a way to use **str_replace** to output this:

```
<h2>Title Here</h2>
```

I can do one side, but not the other??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not with str_replace
But if Title is start of the line, try preg_replace

```
preg_replace('~^(.*?)<!--firstTitle-->~', '<h2>$1</h2>', $string);
```